# scroll happening up after clicking the checkboxes below the scroll bar ones

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4

I have grid with list of checkboxes. When I select one of the checkboxes it scrolls up. It works in Chrome, but it does not work in Firefox. I'm Not sure how to fix it since I am not sure if it is happening due to JS, CSS or HTML.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? I'm providing code below and demo link too:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/cell-editing.html

```
<tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-row-alt">
    <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-common x-grid-cell-first x-grid-cell-selected" id="ext-gen1405">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable" style="; text-align: left;" id="ext-gen1415">Bergamot</div>
    </td>
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1016   ">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable" style="; text-align: left;" id="ext-gen1416">Shade</div>
    </td>
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1017   ">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable" style="; text-align: right;">$7.16</div>
    </td>
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1018   ">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable" style="; text-align: left;" id="ext-gen1409">Apr 27, 2006</div>
    </td>
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-checkcolumn-1019 x-grid-dirty-cell  x-grid-cell-last" id="ext-gen1408">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable" style="; text-align: left;" id="ext-gen1407">
            <div class="x-grid-checkheader" id="ext-gen1406">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you provide a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com). rendered html from an ExtJs application does not really help, we need to see the code and replicate the issue so we can play around with it

Comment: I remember having this issue back in the days of 4.0.x, I think it was fixed with 4.1.0. The most obvious solution would be upgrading to the latest version 4.2.x (or even 5.x if that's an option). ExtJS 4.0.x is loaded with quite many nasty bugs, so I can only recommend taking that step.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue on my grid.
I was created a look like editable cell and every time I post a change to the store the grid got refresh and scroll it back to the top.

What i have done is set **preserveScrollOnRefresh** to true

```
{
  xtype: 'grid',
  colums: [ ... ],
  viewConfig: {
    preserveScrollOnRefresh: true,
  }
}
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-preserveScrollOnRefresh

I hope it will help you.